# Instagram Getting user details

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c, oauth, instagram

Am trying to integrate instagram in my app,while getting user details after getting access token,its showing error . Am appending data in NSData and trying to print it in connectionDidFinishLoading(NSURLConnection *)connection ( NSURLConnection Delegate) . While converting NSData to id ,its showing null .Also if i am converting NSdata to NSString am getting Response as

```
    {"meta":{"error_type":"OAuthAccessTokenException","code":400,"error_message":"The   access_token provided is invalid."}}{"meta":{"code":200},"data":{"username":"XXXX","bio":"","website":"","profile_picture":"http:sampleiamge.jpg","full_name":"samplename","counts":{"media":1,"followed_by":0,"follows":0},"id":"sampleID"}}
```

If am printing the json as  `id jsonData = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:data options:NSJSONReadingMutableContainers error:&error];`
getting error as

> Error Domain=NSCocoaErrorDomain Code=3840 "The operation couldn’t be
>   completed. (Cocoa error 3840.)" (Garbage at end.) UserInfo=0xa967bc0
>   {NSDebugDescription=Garbage at end.}

Tried all jsonreading option ,but no result

Any hep will be appreciable.
Thanks

Comment: did you authenticate before making the request ?

Comment: @Basheer_CAD yes,authenticated using https://instagram.com/oauth/authorize/?client_id=CLIENT-ID&redirect_uri=REDIRECT-URI&response_type=token also getting token

Answer (score 2):

You could also have a look at the InstagramKit which does this fairly straight forward. https://github.com/shyambhat/InstagramKit 
There's a demo app so you can see how the authentication is done and request a user's details in just a few lines of code. You don't really need to mess around with the access token data format.

Answer (score 1):

It seems like you are not authenticate.

There is a project in GitHub that implements a simple UIViewController that performs the Instagram auth process step by step:

https://github.com/Buza/Instagram-Auth-iOS

You can see all process from request token to error management.

Hope it helps!

Answer (score 0):

The response occurs when the `access_token` is invalid, try printing (NSLog) out the URL your are making the request and make sure the `access_token` is correctly passed.

Comment: Krisrak,thanks for the response. Here am giving valid accesstoken,when am executing the same url in the browser and getting correct json as response.But in code,am getting two json files one as error and other contains data of the user.

Comment: post the objective-C code that is making the API request